# Memoir and resize box in LyX

Tags: memoir

I am using `memoir` in Lyx and would like to use `resizebox` for one of my tables, but it does not seem to work. I have written the following

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%

HERE I HAVE INSERTET THE TABLE 

}
```

This provides the following error message

> "missing number, treated as zero illegal unit of measure (pt
>   inserted)"

Any ideas why this does not work? I have tried including the `\noindent` - this does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

Every cloud has a silver lining. That mistake has prevented you from doing that fudge.

The reason of the error is that you have not load the `graphicx` package.

The bad solution: (1) Add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to the LaTeX Preamble  in (Document → Settings...)   or   (2) add some image somewher,  so LyX with load the package automatically. Be sure to make (1) or (2), not (1) and (2).

The good solution: Redesign the table. Without a real example, I exhausted above my daily quota of guesses, but maybe is enough reduce the font size of the table, adjust some header or column width.